# Error in laravel getting elasticsearch instance

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.7 application I want to use elasticsearch and I found this
https://michaelstivala.com/learning-elasticsearch-with-laravel/ article.
Firstly I wanted to import all data from a table I want to use with elasticsearch 
1) I created a wrapper file app/Elastic.php, with content from githubusercontent. Is this proper dir for this file?

2) In my model app/Vote.php I added function

public static function bulkVotesToElastic()
{

```
$elastic = app(App\Elastic\Elastic::class);

Vote::chunk(100, function ($Votes) use ($elastic) {
    foreach ($Votes as $Vote) {
        $elastic->index([
            'index' => 'select_vote',
            'type' => 'vote',
            'id' => $Vote->id,
            'body' => $Vote->toArray()
        ]);
    }
});
```

}

As I have seeder for filling of init data. But calling this method I got error:

```
Class App\App\Elastic\Elastic does not exist
```

Why error and how to fix it?

actually this line

```
$elastic = app(App\Elastic\Elastic::class);
```

is behind my laravel expierence...

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I still search for decision... Did anybody used this librar ?

Comment: can you share your elastic.php ? also try this 

$elastic = app(\App\Elastic\Elastic::class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much a question about Laravel / Elasticsearch but about PHP namespacing and PSR-4 autoloading.

If you look at the `composer.json` file of your Laravel app you will find sth. like

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Which means that you want to follow [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) specification for namespaces inside your `/app` directory. Basically it means your folder structure must correspond to your namespace hierarchy.

**Hence, Problem 1:** You mention to have a class `App\Elastic\Elastic` inside `/app/Elastic.php`. This class cannot be loaded by your PSR-4 autoloader, it should be in `/app/Elastic/Elastic.php` *OR* be declared in the namespace `App\`.

**Problem 2:** When you call

```
$elastic = app(App\Elastic\Elastic::class);
```

inside a namespace, e.g. `App/` it gets resolved to `App/App` as the error says. 
To avoid this, use `\App\Elastic\Elastic::class` as Anar proposes, or import the class via *use* statement.